# Stripe - undefined method Stripe\Subscription::create()

Tags: php, stripe-payments, fatal-error

So I am having a problem creating a stripe payment and keep getting this error.

`<br />↵<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::create() in <b>D:\username\Programs\xampp\htdocs\myapp\services\sec.php</b> on line <b>219</b><br />`

Here is the code.

```
} else if($stripetoken != "") {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "source" => $stripetoken,
    ));


    if ($term == "1") {
        \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(    <-- line 219
            "customer" => $customer->id,
            "plan" => "monthly-sub-test",
        ));                        
    }
```

I believe I have set up the code to what the documentation says

https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

Comment: What version of the PHP library are you using. It sounds like perhaps you are using a version before support for `\Stripe\Subscription::create()` was added.

Comment: My xampp server is running `PHP 5.6.30` if that is what you are asking

Comment: The version of Stripe I was using was version `2.2.0` and way out of date. @Ywain was correct http://stackoverflow.com/a/43494202/5184092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an older version of [Stripe's PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings). The [`\Stripe\Subscription::create()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_subscription) method was added in version [3.13.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3130-2016-05-04). Make sure you're using this version or a more recent one.